# display: block; VS display: table;

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float, clearfix

I can't spot the difference between `display: block;` and `display: table;`. For example, when writing clearfix, the following two CSS rule seems to behaviour identical:

> Using `display: block;`

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <div style="float: right">Sidebar</div>
</div>
<p>
  Content
</p>
```

> Using `display: table;`

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <div style="float: right">Sidebar</div>
</div>
<p>
  Content
</p>
```

So my question is: What's the differences between `display: block;` and `display: table;`?

Comment: go through this article: http://blog.karenmenezes.com/2014/apr/13/floats-inline-block-or-display-table-or-flexbox/

Comment: You won't see a difference for your example.The use of display:table in the [micro clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) is for the benefit of the `::before` pseudo-element, used to stop the top margins of child elements from collapsing with the container element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the demo below, the `display: table;` applied on `.clearfix::after` prevents the bottom margin of last child of `clearfix` from collapsing with the bottom margin of `clearfix` itself, while `display: table;` still allows collapsing.

```css
.clearfix_table,
.clearfix_block {
  background-color: silver;
}
.clearfix_table::after,
.clearfix_block::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix_table::after {
  display: table;
}
.clearfix_block::after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix_table">
  <p>text</p>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="clearfix_block">
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the clearfix hack, the difference is much clearer!

```html
<p>With display:table you get</p>

<div style="display:table; border:1px solid">
  This is a table
</div>

<p>And with display:block you get</p>

<div style="display:block; border:1px solid">
  This is a block
</div>
```

So for a little food for though, you could have asked what the difference is between `display:table` and `display:inline-block` instead...

Comment: I suspect the asker is asking the wrong question altogether, and that they don't actually mean to ask what the difference is between display: table and display: block or inline-block.